# IdleDetectionMode error Windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a checkbox. On it's checked event I want to turn off IdleDetectionMode and on unchecked event I want to turn on. This is the code :-

```
private void chkRunInBackground_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;

        }

        private void chkRunInBackground_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Enabled;

        }
```

The checked event runs fine but on unchecked event I get, IdleDetection mode cannot be started once it is disabled. Why is this restriction applied and what can I do to work around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941090%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

> In the current release, application
>   idle detection cannot be enabled in a
>   single application instance once it
>   has been disabled. Doing so throws an
>   exception. In future releases this may
>   be supported, so your application may
>   choose to disable application idle
>   detection when it is no longer needed
>   and catch the expected exception.

The following code snippet shows an implementation of this.

```
// Custom function to turn off idle detection. This will throw an exception in the current release.
public void TryReenableApplicationIdleDetection()
{
    bool didEnable = false;
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode =
            Microsoft.Phone.Shell.IdleDetectionMode.Enabled;
        didEnable = true;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        // This exception is expected in the current release.
    }

    // possibly use the value of didEnable to decide what to do next
    // if it is 'true' then your app will be deactivated 
    // if it is 'false' then your app will keep running
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941090%28VS.92%29.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.PHONE.SHELL.PHONEAPPLICATIONSERVICE.APPLICATIONIDLEDETECTIONMODE%29;k%28APPLICATIONIDLEDETECTIONMODE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true):

> In the current release, application
>   idle detection cannot be enabled in a
>   single  application instance once it
>   has been disabled. Doing so throws an
>   exception.

Basically, the application defines it's characteristics that will determine the system behavior and "attitude" towards it. It is a bad practice to try and change those while the application is running.